# HTML: Have text areas on left and right side of screen

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make it so I can have a page with a text area aligned left and a text area aligned right. Currently I can only get it to work with one aligned left. Here is my code so far.

---

```css
 div {
    height: 90px;
    line-height: 90px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 2px dashed #f69c55;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
  
    <h1 align = "center"> Chat Room </h1>
    <form>

    Chat <br>
    <textarea rows="20" cols = "100"> </textarea>
    <br> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Chat">
    </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: Where is the other textarea? I only see one.

Comment: I don't have it in here because I'm not sure how to implement it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the following CSS to the `textarea`.

```
display: inline-block;
width: 48.5%; /* allowing for margin, paddings, outlines, etc. */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<style>
div {
height: 90px;
line-height: 90px;
text-align: left;
border: 2px dashed #f69c55;
}
textarea {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 48.5%;
}
</style>

<div>

<h1 align = "center"> Chat Room </h1>
<form>

Chat <br>
<textarea rows="20" cols = "100"> </textarea>
<textarea rows="20" cols = "100"> </textarea>
<br> <br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Chat">
</form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
..
#tx1{
float: left;
}
#tx2{
float: right;
}
</style>
..
<textarea id="tx1" rows="20" cols = "100"> </textarea>
<textarea id="tx2"rows="20" cols = "100"> </textarea>
```

missing the second text area?